# Function Variable passed to setTimeout not working?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

```
function changeBG(element_id){
        document.getElementById(element_id).className= "arrowActive";
        setTimeout("document.getElementById("+element_id+").className= 'arrow'", 300);
}
```

In firebug I get an error saying that the element_id passed to setTimeout() is not defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `element_id` will be a string, so your timeout code will look like:

```
document.getElementById(myId).className = ...
```

Notice that myId should be in quotes, but it's not.

A better way is to use a closure, like this:

```
function changeBG(element_id)
{
        var elm = document.getElementById(element_id);
        elm.className = "arrowActive";
        setTimeout(function() { elm.className= 'arrow'; }, 300);
}
```

It should be noted that passing the code in a a string is [not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/window.setTimeout).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + element_id + "').className= 'arrow'", 300);
```

Notice that I added quotes to the string parameter you're passing to `getElementById`.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is with a closure

```
function changeBG(element_id)
{
        var elem = document.getElementById(element_id);
        elem.className= "arrowActive";
        setTimeout( function(e)
        {
                return function()
                {
                        e.className = 'arrow';
                }
        }( elem ), 300);
}
```